# Android Countdown timer, does not reattach to activity after exiting

Tags: android, timer

I am creating an App to track poker tournaments.

With this I am using a Custom CountDown timer to keep track of my tournament rounds.

Class is below

```
public class TournamentTimer extends CountDownTimer {
private int mRound;
private TextView mBlindsTextView;
private TextView mTimeTextView;
private TextView mRoundTextView;
private Context mContext;
private View mrootView;
private int numberOfBreaks = 0;

public TournamentTimer(Context context, long timeLimit, int round, View rootView) {
    super(timeLimit, 1000);
    mContext = context;
    mRound = round;
    mBlindsTextView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.blinds);
    mTimeTextView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.timer);
    mRoundTextView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.roundTracker);
    mRoundTextView.setText(String.format(mContext.getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.Round), mRound));
    mBlindsTextView.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.Blinds, Blinds.DEFAULT_BLINDS1500[mRound - 1], Blinds.DEFAULT_BLINDS1500[mRound - 1] * 2));
    mrootView = rootView;
    mTimeTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            start();
        }
    });
}


@Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    long minutesLeft = millisUntilFinished / 60000;
    long secondsLeft = (millisUntilFinished % 60000) / 1000;
    String timeLeft;
    if (secondsLeft >= 10)
        timeLeft = mContext.getString(R.string.TimeLeft, minutesLeft, secondsLeft);
    else timeLeft = mContext.getString(R.string.TimeLeftWithPadding, minutesLeft, secondsLeft);
    mTimeTextView.setText(timeLeft);
}

public void onFinish() {
    mRound = mRound + 1;
    mRoundTextView.setText(String.format(mContext.getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.Round), mRound - numberOfBreaks));
    mBlindsTextView.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.Blinds, Blinds.DEFAULT_BLINDS1500[mRound - 1 - numberOfBreaks], Blinds.DEFAULT_BLINDS1500[mRound - 1 - numberOfBreaks] * 2));
    //Will Keep cycling through rounds until the tournament is manually ended.
    if (mRound % 4 == 0) {
        mRoundTextView.setText(R.string.Break);
        numberOfBreaks++;

    }
    this.start();
}
}
```

My on create of the activity that displays the timer creates a new timer.

I cancel the timer when the activity stops.

When I resume the activity I Restart the timer, and it starts, but the Views on the screen do not get updated.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

I was able to get this to work. I added a variable for milliseconds remaining and updated it every on tick.

Then in my main activity I grabbed this new variable as well as the round variable in onStop (Cancel the timer as well) and created a new timer with these values in on create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work. I added a variable for milliseconds remaining and updated it every on tick.

Then in my main activity I grabbed this new variable as well as the round variable in onStop (Cancel the timer as well) and created a new timer with these values in on create